# optimal separating hyperplane objective function confusion

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

[Chapter 4.5.2 of Elements of Statistical Learning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYn2C.jpg)

I don't understand what does it mean：

＂Since for any β and β0 satisfying these inequalities, any positively scaled
multiple satisfies them too, we can arbitrarily set ||β|| = 1/M.＂

Also, how does maximize M becomes minimize 1/2(||β||^2) ?

Answer (score 0):

> ＂Since for any β and β0 satisfying these inequalities, any positively scaled multiple satisfies them too, we can arbitrarily set ||β|| = 1/M.＂

```
y_i(x_i' b + b0) >= M ||b||
```

thus for any c>0

```
y_i(x_i' [bc] + [b0c]) >= M ||bc||
```

thus you can always find such c that ||bc|| = 1/M, so we can focus only on b such that they have such norm (we simply limit the space of possible solutions because we know that scaling does not change much)

> Also, how does maximize M becomes minimize 1/2(||β||^2) ?

We put ||b|| = 1/M, thus M=1/||b||

```
max_b M = max_b 1 / ||b||
```

now maximization of **positive** f(b) is equivalent of minimization of 1/f(b), so

```
min ||b||
```

and since ||b|| is positive, its minimization is equivalent to minimization of the square, as well as multiplied by 1/2 (this does not change the optimal b)

```
min 1/2 ||b||^2
```